# I cannot make a good API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a weather app project. My problem is that when I try to access the list property with the map method in that API, I get an error:

```
react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I think the problem is that the return method is executed before API is not called. So, the code throws this error. How I can fix it?

The ApiCall commponent:

```
function ApiCall({ getSelection }) {
  const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${getSelection}&appid="Here is the API key" `)
        setTakeData(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
      setLoading(false)
    }
    fetchApi()
  }, [getSelection])

  if (loading===true) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  
  const { city, list } = takeData
  // console.log("IS UPDATED: ",city?.name)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        // use map method since it is a list
        list.map(el => el[0].main.temp)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is the data from API

```
list: Array(40)
0:
clouds: {all: 0}
dt: 1660726800
dt_txt: "2022-08-17 09:00:00"
main: {temp: 299.42, feels_like: 299.42, temp_min: 299.42, temp_max: 301.99, pressure: 1006, …}
pop: 0
sys: {pod: 'd'}
visibility: 10000
weather: [{…}]
wind: {speed: 2.31, deg: 292, gust: 3.03}
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {dt: 1660737600, main: {…}, weather: Array(1), clouds: {…}, wind: {…}, …}
2: {dt: 1660748400, main: {…}, weather: Array(1), clouds: {…}, wind: {…}, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `list.map()` is called before the fetch is complete. To fix it, you need to ensure `list` is an array when `map()` function is called on it. One way to do that is to set a default empty array, like this:

```js
const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState({list: []})
```

Alternatively, you may call `map()` with an optional chaining operator `?.` similar to how you have used it in the commented out line for `city?.name`. So:

```js
  return (
    <div>
      {list?.map(el => el[0].main.temp)}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the render method of the component is trying to use `list` state before you assign a value to it, that is why you get the `undefined` error.

Try checking the list value before you can use it, like so:

```js
return (
    <div>
      {
        // check if list is not undefined AND has at least one item
        // you can be more creative with your check here, and display another message if there are no items for example
        if (list && list?.length > 0) {
           // use map method since it is a list
           list.map(el => el[0].main.temp)
        }
        else {
           Loading...
        }
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Another way could be using your `loading` state like this:

```js
if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

return (
  <div>
    list.map(el => el[0].main.temp)
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**before api call you should setLoading true for render  Loading... html**

```
function ApiCall({ getSelection }) {
  const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
    setLoading(true); // before api call you should setLoading true for render <div>Loading...</div> html
      try {
        const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${getSelection}&appid="Here is the API key" `)
        setTakeData(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
      setLoading(false)
    }
    fetchApi()
  }, [getSelection])

  if (loading===true) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  
  const { city, list } = takeData
  // console.log("IS UPDATED: ",city?.name)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        // use map method since it is a list
        list?.map(el => el[0].main.temp) // <=== also use optional chaining
      }
    </div>
  )

}
```