# I am getting "undefined" in my API call - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a weather app project. Until now, I ran into many issues with API call. I think the reason is my code is executed before the API call is not completed. So, I always get errors like below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'list' of 'takeData' as it is undefined
```

Other errors were solved. There was no such error before I try to add weather icons into my project. I have two questions:

1. How to fix the error above
2. Why whenever I try to add something new into the project, does it throw error "undefined"

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCloudSun } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faCloud } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


function ApiCall({ getSelection }) {
  const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const cloudSun = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloudSun} />
  const cloud = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloud} />


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      try {
        const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${getSelection}&units=metric&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
        setTakeData(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      setLoading(false)
    }
    fetchApi()
  }, [getSelection])

  if (loading === true) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  const { list } = takeData
  // console.log("IS UPDATED: ",city?.name)

  return (
    <div className="weather_card">
      <div className="weather">{list?.map((el, idx) => (
        <p key={idx} style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "10px", paddingTop: "165px", boxSizing: "border-box", height: "200px", width: "150px", border: "1px solid grey" }} >{Math.round(el.main.temp)} °C / {el.weather[0].main} </p>
      ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ApiCall
```

Comment: I already answer this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384974/i-cannot-make-a-good-api-call/73385046#73385046) on your previous post

Comment: The code you wrote gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an initial value for takeData so that the application doesn't error out

```
const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState({list:[]})
```

Comment: İt worked. Thanks. But, I did not understand why you initialized list array in the state